# "AC BACK" option in Gigabyte BIOS is greyed out

Tags: bios, motherboard, power-management, desktop-computer

I want to make my desktop PC turn itself back on after a power outage, so I had a look in the BIOS. There is an option called "AC BACK" which seems to be what I'm looking for, but it's greyed out.

[image]

Does this mean the motherboard doesn't support these options, or that I have to do something to enable them?

Comment: Maybe Platform Power Management needs to be enabled…?

Comment: @DanielB I edited the question, the new photo shows how it looks when Platform Power Management is enabled. It just adds the three ASPM options, but the other options remain greyed out.